# Default Date Patterns in Windows server 2012 has changed

Tags: c#, datetime-format, windows-server-2012

Long Date Pattern for en-US in Windows server 2012 (dddd, MMMM d, yyyy) is different than what it used to be on older windows versions (dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy), and since any .net application inherits the default culture formats from system the following code blocks generate different outputs based on windows version.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo myDTFI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
Console.WriteLine("  {0}     {1}", "en-US", myDTFI.LongDatePattern);

myDTFI = new CultureInfo("tr-TR", false).DateTimeFormat;
Console.WriteLine("  {0}     {1}", "tr-TR", myDTFI.ShortDatePattern);
```

This finding is contrary to what is being stated on the Examples section of the MSDN article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longdatepattern.aspx

I have also updated my server but the difference still continues. Can you please verify that it is also the same on your Windows 2012 servers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default datetime settings on the server as described in this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2905782

> To work around this change, revert the date formats to the original formats that are mentioned in the "Summary" section. To do this, use the Change date, time or number formats item in Control Panel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your comment on how to change it, but it doesn't really answer the question on if/why it was changed.

Comment: I had the same problem after upgrading a web server to Windows Server 2012. ASP.NET applications started to generate datetime values in unexpected format. Changing default values for the cultureinfo in control panels helped me to solve the problem...

Comment: That begs the question of why are you relying on a specific local time format,  especially the long time format. There are time formats designed explicitly for round trip use.

Comment: @Keeble could you please explain how to change default value of date formats for the specific cultureinfo in control panel? I had similar problem but the language on the server set to Dutch (Belgium) and application uses French (Belguim) culture which displays wrong format.